# How would I change this java method, to not rely on lotNumber - 1

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Objects First with Java

A Practical Introduction using BlueJ

Working threw this book and I do not understand what this exercise is asking me to do.

The exercise is...

Exercise 4.51 Rewrite getLot so that it does not rely on a lot with a particular number being stored at index (number–1) in the collection. For instance, if lot number 2 has been removed, then lot number 3 will have been moved from index 2 to index 1, and all higher lot numbers will also have been moved by one index position. You may assume that lots are al- ways stored in increasing order according to their lot numbers.

```
    /**
         * Return the lot with the given number. Return null if a lot with this
         * number does not exist.
         *
         * @param lotNumber The number of the lot to return.
         */
        public Lot getLot(int lotNumber) {
            if ((lotNumber >= 1) && (lotNumber < nextLotNumber)) {
                // The number seems to be reasonable.
                Lot selectedLot = lots.get(lotNumber - 1);
                // Include a confidence check to be sure we have the
                // right lot.
                if (selectedLot.getNumber() != lotNumber) {
                    System.out.println("Internal error: Lot number "
                            + selectedLot.getNumber()
                            + " was returned instead of "
                            + lotNumber);
                    // Don't return an invalid lot.
                    selectedLot = null;
                }
                return selectedLot;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Lot number: " + lotNumber
                        + " does not exist.");
                return null;
            }
        }
```

A hint in the right direction with pesudo code would be fine.
I am really confused in what the exercise is asking me to do.

I will be upfront about this, this is for a class and the teacher is really just handing us the book, with very little guidance. So I am not looking for someone to write my homework, I just want some help. Please don't flame me because I am asking. This is a place to ask questions about coding? No? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm of the given method relies on lot `lotNumber` being stored in index `lotNumber-1`. It just looks it up by index and verifies it has found the correct one.

The exercise is to give up this assumption. Lot number and index are no longer this closely related. So you cannot just calculate the index, you have to *search* for the lot.

The simplest possible approach is to look at each lot in your collection and return it once you found a matching lot number. You can use an iterator, explicitly or implicitly ("foreach"), for this. If your course hasn't covered iterators yet, you can also use a `for` loop to count through all existing indexes of your collection.

But the exercise specifies that the lots are still stored in order. This allows you to modify the simple approach to give up once you found a lot number higher than the one you're looking for.

The optimal approach would be using a *search algorithm* for sorted lists, such as [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search).

Answer (score 0):

In the code you provided, there is a big assumption: the assumption that lot number `i` is stored in the array at the position `i-1`. Now what if we don't assume that? Well we have no idea where lot `i` might be in the array, so the only solution is to go through the array and look for lot number `i` and hopefully we'll found it.